# Ajax updateProgress does not show progress for the right UpdatePannel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have an Ajax panel `first panel` inside another panel `second panel` and an `updateProgress` linked to the first panel

With this I have two problems:

- The updateProgress show the progress image when the second panel updates but not when the first panel updates
- To update the 2nd panel I have to press the button inside the second panel twice

  ```
  <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UProc_TabContainer" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UP_FirstPanel"
  DisplayAfter="1">
  <ProgressTemplate>
      <div id="dvProgress" runat="server" style="position: absolute; top: 300px; left: 450px;
          text-align: center;">
          <asp:Image ID="wait" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/wait3.gif" Height="120px"
              Width="128px" />
      </div>
  </ProgressTemplate>
  </asp:UpdateProgress>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_FirstPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
      <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
          function divexpandcollapse(divname) {
              var div = document.getElementById(divname);
              var img = document.getElementById('img' + divname);
              if (div.style.display == "none") {
                  div.style.display = "block"; img.src = "Images/Icons/minus.jpg";
              } else { div.style.display = "none"; img.src = "Images/Icons/plus.jpg"; }
          }</script>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="DateSelection" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" Height="21px"
          Width="134px">
      </asp:DropDownList>
      <asp:GridView ID="GV_SL" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gvUserInfo_RowDataBound"
          OnRowCommand="GV_SL_RowCommand" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="SQL_Weekly">
          <Columns>
              <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="50px">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div<%# Eval("name") %>');">
                          <img id="imgdiv<%# Eval("name") %>" width="15px" border="0" src="Images/Icons/plus.jpg" /></a></ItemTemplate>
                  <ItemStyle Width="40px" />
              </asp:TemplateField>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Group" SortExpression="name" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="ASL" HeaderText="SL% Act" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ASL" />
              <asp:TemplateField>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                      <tr>
                          <td colspan="100%">
                              <div id="div<%# Eval("name") %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 15px;
                                  overflow: auto">
                                  <asp:GridView ID="gvChildGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                                      <Columns>
                                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Metric" HeaderText=" " HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                          <asp:BoundField DataField="Actual" HeaderText="Actual" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                                      </Columns>
                                  </asp:GridView>
                                  <br />
                                  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_SecondPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
                                      <ContentTemplate>
                                          <%--  --%>
                                          <asp:TextBox ID="TB_Comments" runat="server" Text="Example: Text will be entered here"
                                              TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="4" Width="510px"></asp:TextBox>
                                          <asp:Button ID="B_Save" runat="server" CommandName="AddText" CommandArgument="<%# CType(Container,GridViewRow).RowIndex %>"
                                              Text="Save Changes" />
                                      </ContentTemplate>
                                  </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                  <%--  --%>
                              </div>
                          </td>
                      </tr>
                  </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
      </asp:GridView>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DateSelection" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
  </Triggers>
  ```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I have resolved the 1st problem by removing AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UP_FirstPanel" from the UpdateProgress. The second problem is rather more strange. Once I load the page the 2nd panel updates, but if I change the value in the drop down, then I have to press twice the B_Save button to update the 2nd panel

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the 1st problem presented by removing AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UP_FirstPanel" from the UpdateProgress. I hope it helps someone

I've created a separate posting with further detail and simplified code for the second problem ([Nested Ajax UpdatePanel in Gridview needs button control to be clicked twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047300/vb-net-nested-ajax-updatepanel-in-gridview-needs-button-control-to-be-clicked))